# multidimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In java, multidimensional arrays of objects diclared like this (A is type of object):

```
A[][] array = new A[5][5];

for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<5;j++){
        array[i][j] = new A();
    }
}
```

how can I do the same in C++?

Comment: You can use a `std::vector<std::vector<A>>` to do the same in c++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Its not the same.... I need to make **object** array and not **variable** array (e.g. float or integer)

Comment: @gal What do you think is the difference? There isn't any.

Comment: Don't use multi-dimensional arrays in C++ (or in C).

Comment: Basile is right. It's possible to declare a 3D array in C/C++ but causes too many problems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why not?

Comment: Define your own `Matrix`  class. Or use `std::array<std::array<A,5>,5>`

Answer (score 1):

Another idea for a multi dimensional array is if you use std::vector

```
#include <vector>

class A{
//Set properties here
};

int main(){

   //Init vector
   std::vector<std::vector<A>> array;

   std::vector<A> tempVec;

   for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){

       for(int j = 0;j<5;j++){
           A aValue;

           //Set properties for object A here

           tempVec.push_back(aValue);
       }
       array.push_back(tempVec);
   }
}
```

The good thing about a vector is that there is no limit to the amount of items;

Answer (score 1):

Unless I have misunderstood your question in some way, to declare a two-dimensional array in C++ you could use this:

```
A variable; // Declares a variable of A type, named variable
A array[5][5] = {{ variable, variable, variable, variable, variable },
                        { variable, variable, variable, variable, variable },
                        { variable, variable, variable, variable, variable },
                        { variable, variable, variable, variable, variable },
                        { variable, variable, variable, variable, variable }};
```

If you think of a two-dimensional array as a virtual table, you just declare the values by row, each row is a set of curly brackets, then surround the whole table with a final set of brackets.

If you are in love with for loops you can still use them:

```
A variable;
A array[5][5];
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++){
        array[row][col] = variable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the code like this:

```
A array[5][5];
```

It will create the 2D array and it will initialize each cell with A object. This piece of code equals to the code in Java like this:

```
A[][] array = new A[5][5];

for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j<5;j++){
        array[i][j] = new A();
    }
}
```

Full code which works properly:

```
class A{};
int main() {
    A array[5][5];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its the same code I wrote in java.... anyway, when I compile this code i get an error:

Comment: Its in another file. I imported it in the start of the main file.

Comment: Array creates properly, the problem is with your code. Please, post your code, or create another question with the problem you have now.

Comment: The problem is that I can't create the objects like this:    array[i][j] = new A(); Its says:   error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'A' and 'A*')

Comment: @gal Stop using `new` in c++. It's wrong in most cases.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ so how can I create C++ objects in arrays?

Comment: @galaharon You didn't get what we were telling you. You don't need to create them, they are already instatiated. If you want to assign some different instance, you have to overload the assignment operator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just tutor them how to delete arrays in heap

Comment: @Sugar In most cases you don't need and want to use `new` and `delete` in modern c++.